# Find common function in decompiled scripts

Tags: refactoring, reverse-engineering

I have a bunch of decompiled scripts that look like C code.

These scripts were decompiled (I cannot really tell exactly how), so they were not written as-is by humans.

However they show some very interesting patterns that lead me to think that the decompiler duplicated some functions in most of the scripts because it followed the execution path.

For example most of the scripts have a function like:

```
void *fct_9887(int param_123, char param_864) {
  fct_4698(param_75, param_83);
  return CORE_FUNCTION(param_864, param_123);
}
```

But for each scripts, function names and parameters names are different. So the exact same function will appear in another script like

```
void *fct_57(int param_93, char param_75) {
  fct_1000(param_75, param_83);
  return CORE_FUNCTION(param_75, param_83);
}
```

As you can guess here, `fct_4698` and `fct_1000` are also identical, making these too functions duplicated code.

Some of the functions actually keep the same name across all the scripts (here, CORE_FUNCTION), because are external functions, and thus shared between scripts

I am trying to find a way to "re-factor" this and try to extract common function used in these scripts. I know it will sometimes not be possible but for some functions it should be possible.

How would you proceed to do such a thing?

Comment: What language are you working with? Are you recompiling after your refactoring? If not what are you doing? To what end are you refactoring?

Comment: I am working with code that is very close to C, but is not C. I am not recompiling after. The end is to make the decompiled code clearer so it is easier to understand and thus to reverse engineer

Comment: Can you get unit tests around the code?

Comment: I have no way to test: I do not have access to a compiler nor to the decompiler. At the same time I do not want something that is perfect. I just want to remove some obvious duplicated code so reading the decompiled file becomes easier :)